# Align image to the bottom of a left-floated div

Tags: html, css, positioning

Trying to create a WEB interface for my local collection of comic books. The look'n'feel should be very similar to Apple's iBooks - book covers sittings on the bookshelves. The covers are similar but not identical in height and width. Can't figure out how to push the image covers to the bottom of the div without indicating the width of the containing div. Going with absolute-inside-relative simply stacks the covers into a pile.

HTML:

```
<div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="cover1.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="cover2.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="cover"><a href="#"><img src="cover3.jpg"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background-image: url(http://image.bayimg.com/oaddpaaea.jpg); background-repeat: repeat;}
.cover {float: left; height: 258px; border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px 5px 25px 5px;}
.cover img {border: 1px solid green; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;}
```

jsFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NATqD/

Comment: Hey 1695953 ! Interesting question (+1), although the jsfiddle probably doesn't show what you want to show

Comment: Is this what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NATqD/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
.cover {  float: left; height: 258px;line-height: 258px;  border: 1px solid red; margin: 0px 5px 25px 5px;}
.cover img {vertical-align: bottom; border: 1px solid green; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black; box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;}
```

You add `line-height: 258px` to match the height of the cover div. Then `vertical-align: bottom` on the images. Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NATqD/6/

Comment: BTW, I took Fredy's idea a bit further. It seems logical to keep the covers centered on any given shelf. Murged all wrapper div's into a single p with text-align centered. Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/FTrGs/

Answer (score 1):

This seems the most straight-forward to me:

```
<div class="cover">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.emeraldinsight.com/fig/53_10_1108_S0731-9053_2009_0000024005.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://roborfid.dyndns.org/data/book_images/backs_small/SIWE_R_GM00404130.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://roborfid.dyndns.org/data/book_images/backs_small/SIWE_R_GM00624371.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.lauren-myers.com/_img/right_arrow.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.gotohoroscope.com/img/bg_00.gif"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://roborfid.dyndns.org/data/book_images/backs_small/SIWE_R_GM00404091.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.startplay.co.uk/images/play.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://www.educorporatebridge.com/old_back_up_16-07-12/images/foundcourses.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s1.hao123.com/index/images/temple_bg.gif"></a>
</div>

.cover {
    line-height: 258px;
    height: 258px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    margin: 0px 5px 25px 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NATqD/5/

Works in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: As soon as you change the viewport width/height (browser window size) it pushes out all images outside of the containing div instead of reflowing the covers alongside the shelves.

Comment: You can manipulate the `font-size` and `line-height` to find the right mix. This seems to make it wrap around exactly, although I imagine you have a shelf below the books to compensate for: http://jsfiddle.net/NATqD/9/

Answer (score 0):

Add the position: relative to the .cover this allows you to add the position: absolute to the image and thus you can position the images absolutely relative to the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/NATqD/1/

Comment: In his question he said that he did not want to specify a width on the container. Your answer includes one.

Comment: That's right. I don't want to hard-code the width or set in a run-time. The idea is to let the div to wrap the containing cover image.

Comment: why dont you want to use width? Is it because the cover images are different sizes?